# Return a percentage of NULL values for a specific record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The following query returns the values of the table for each field in terms of null percentage . What I want is to get the sum of those percentages for a specific ProductID. Also, I would like to get a percentage (in an extra column) of the fields do not have value i.e. ="".  Any ideas?

```
use AdventureWorks 
DECLARE @TotalCount decimal(10,2), @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @TotalCount = COUNT(*) FROM [AdventureWorks].[Production].[Product] 

SELECT @SQL = 

COALESCE(@SQL + ', ','SELECT ') +
'cast(sum (case when ' + QUOTENAME(column_Name) + 
' IS NULL then 1 else 0 end)/@TotalCount*100.00 as decimal(10,2)) as [' +
column_Name + ' NULL %]
'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Product' and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'Production'
SET @SQL = 'set @TotalCount = NULLIF(@TotalCount,0) 
' + @SQL + '
FROM [AdventureWorks].Production.Product'
print @SQL
EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL, N'@TotalCount decimal(10,2)', @TotalCount
```

Comment: Surely you know the schema of `[AdventureWorks].[Production].[Product]`, why use dynamic SQL? Are you trying to show how denormalization leads to sparse population?

Comment: @Jodrell I mean dynamic sql in order to get all the fields of the table. We sometimes add fields from queries in the table so we don't want to modify the particular (percentage) query for every field change/addition.

Comment: By "sum of those percentages for a specific ProductID", do you mean the sum of the percentage for all columns of the table, but only taking into account the records that have a certain product id (which in fact should just be one record)?

Comment: @FrankPl No, I meant the average (sum/number of columns). For example the percentage of fields that have a null value of ProductID=123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
use AdventureWorks

DECLARE @colCount int;
DECLARE @nullCheck nvarchar(max) = N'';
DECLARE @emptyCheck nvarchar(max) = N'';
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @KeyToCheck int = 123; -- adapt as necessary

SELECT 
    @nullCheck += '
         + ' + 'count(' + QUOTENAME(column_Name) + ')'
   ,@emptyCheck += '
         + ' +
         CASE
             WHEN DATA_TYPE IN('bigint', 'int', 'smallint', 'tinyint', 'bit', 'money', 'smallmoney', 'numeric', 'decimal', 'float', 'real') THEN
                 -- check numeric data for zero
                 'sum(case when coalesce(' + QUOTENAME(column_Name) + ', 0) = 0 then 1 else 0 end)' 
             WHEN DATA_TYPE like '%char' or DATA_TYPE like '%text' THEN 
                 --check character data types for empty string
                 'sum(case when coalesce(' + QUOTENAME(column_Name) + ', '''') = '''' then 1 else 0 end)'
             ELSE -- otherwise, only check for null
                 'sum(case when ' + QUOTENAME(column_Name) + ' IS NULL then 1 else 0 end)'
         END
   ,@colCount = 
        count(*) over()

FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Product' and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'Production'
;

SET @SQL = 'SELECT case when count(*) > 0 then 100.00 - (' + @nullCheck + '
      ) * 100.00 / ' + cast(@colCount as nvarchar(max)) + '.00 / count(*) end as null_percent
      , case when count(*) > 0 then (' + @emptyCheck + '
      ) * 100.00 / ' + cast(@colCount as nvarchar(max)) + '.00 / count(*) end as empty_percent
FROM Production.Product
WHERE ProductID = ' + cast(@KeyToCheck as nvarchar(max))
;

print @SQL;

EXECUTE (@SQL)
```

I simplified one of your expressions: Instead of `sum (case when <column> IS NULL then 1 else 0 end)`, you can just use `count(<column>)`. When using `count` with an expression instead of `*`, it counts the rows where this expression is non-null. As this is the opposite from what you need, I added the `100.00 -` as the start of the `SELECT`.

For the "empty check", this would make the logic more complex to understand, hence I left the original logic there and extended it. There, I implemented an check for emptiness for numeric and character/text data types. You can easily extend that for date, binary data etc. with whichever logic you use to determine if a column is empty.

I also found it more simple to leave first `+` in the two variables `@nullCheck` and `@emptyCheck`, as it is valid SQL to start an expression wit this.

I also extended the statement so that if there would potentially be more than one record with `ProductId = 123`, it shows the average across all records, i. e. the total sum divided by the count of rows. And the outermost `case` expressions just avoid an division by zero error if `count(*)` would be zero, i. e. no record with `ProductId = 123` found. In that case the return value is `null`.

Comment: Your answer works. Could you please complete it by the second part which is: Also, I would like to get a percentage (in an extra column) of the fields do not have value i.e. ="". This means to get the percentage you return  with the fields that are null or "" combined.

Comment: @nectarines You obviously want to check for empty text only in text columns. How should integer, float, date, binary, ... columns be checked?

Comment: Integers - 0, dates (im not sure-please advise), binaries-not any. That should be all.

Comment: Your answer is superb! Great stuff!

Comment: Also, if I want to get the results from three specific columns, how should I edit the query?

Comment: @nectarines Just add them to the `SELECT` list with any aggregation that makes sense for the type of column, e. g like `SELECT case ... end as null_percent, case  ... end as empty_percent, max(your_column1), avg(your_column2), min(your_column3) FROM ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `AVG` function:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN value IS NULL THEN 100 ELSE 0 END) AS Percents
FROM Table
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is your script:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX), @TABLE_NAME NVARCHAR(MAX), @TABLE_SCHEMA NVARCHAR(MAX), @PK NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @TABLE_NAME = 'tblBigTable'
SET @TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
SET @PK = '8'

SELECT
    @SQL = COALESCE(@SQL + ', ', 'SELECT ') +'AVG(CASE WHEN ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' IS NULL THEN 100 ELSE 0 END) AS [' + COLUMN_NAME +' NULL %]'
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    TABLE_SCHEMA = @TABLE_SCHEMA AND 
    TABLE_NAME = @TABLE_NAME

SET @SQL = @SQL + ' FROM ' + @TABLE_NAME + ' WHERE pkId = ''' + @PK + ''''

print @SQL

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

Comment: that is for a specific field. I want the query to be dynamic and include all the fields without specifying the column name.

Comment: Edited my answer so it is generic and you can pass in schema, table name and id

Comment: In your answer all the fields get returned. What i want is to turn only one number i.e. [tableProduct]-97% nulls